# Python Pig Latin Translator

Tags: python

So I have been working over at Codecademy.com for a while trying to learn python. I don't really know if I am just blind and can't see why this won't work or what. Here's the code it won't let me use. Its function is to print the variable if what I had actually typed something in and print "empty" if I didn't type anything.

```
print "Welcome to the English to Pig Latin translator!"
original = raw_input("What's your name?")
if len(original) > 0
        print original
    else
        print "empty"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is a **question**-and-**answer** site, but your post lacks a question.  What is your question?

Comment: So you always get `empty` as the output?

Comment: Your code does not use valid Python syntax. The indentation is incorrect, and you are missing the colons on the `if` and `else` statements.

Comment: Also, try to be clearer in the question title. It doesn't have anything to do with Pig Latin I'm afraid...

Comment: because my answer was downvoted like crazy I will put it in a comment. It might be good to add the python version you are using. As print is a function in python3 and should then be written as print("welcome...").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if len(original) > 0
else
```

The above lines contains syntax errors. Try:

```
if len(original) > 0:
else:
```

Note the added colons, (`:`).

Answer (score 0):

If the env is linux, try using the below code. And please see find out what is the difference with your code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "Welcome to the English to Pig Latin translator!"
original = raw_input("What's your name?")
if len(original) > 0:
    print original
else:
    print "empty"
```